# Blockly code for translate numbers roman

Tags: blockly

I need to do a progam in blockly code for translate numbers from arabigos to roman up to 4000,but I don't know what I am doing wrong .

I only can use functions ,variables ,maths and logic   (attached html code ).
who can help me with this please ,I'll be thankful ;))

https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/demos/code/index.html#zq536j

Comment: This is a very broad and unresearched question. Please tell us what u tried, what worked and what didn't. Also, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hello ,I have tried different ways but I do not know how to get to the solution :( thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I can think of something :)

Perhaps an example can help me: n = 1234 I can start by dividing by 1000 and take the integer part:

```
M = Math.floor(n/1000)
```

now M is 1 Now I can remove 1000*M from n and continue: 
   n = n-1000*M -> so now n is only 234.

After that:

```
   D = Math.floor(n/500)
   n = n-500*D
```

so D is 0 and n is still 234, because 234 does not contain any 500-eds.

And so no:

```
   C = Math.floor(n/100)
   n = n-100*C
```

which gives that C is 2 and n is 34.

And so on:

```
   L = Math.floor(n/50)
   n = n-50*L
```

which gives that L is 0 and n is 34.

Then:

```
   X = Math.floor(n/10)
   n = n-10*X
```

which gives that X is 3 and n is 4. 
And finally

```
   I = n
```

So now:

```
   M=1
   D=0
   C=2
   L=0
   X=3
   I=4
```

so you just have to make a clever enough function that prints it like:

```
   "M CC XXX IV"
```

and you are done ;)

PS I hope this was not homework :D